# Failed to fetch medibuntu Something wicked happened resolving (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

Tags: linux-mint, apt

I'm using linux mint, and while executing `apt-get install <some-package>` i encounter some errors. The errors from `install` are:

```
E: Encountered a section with no Package: header
E: Problem with MergeList /var/lib/apt/list/packages.medibuntu.org_dists_quantal_free_i18n_Translation-en
E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.
```

I run `apt-get update` and got a few errors. Here is the contents of the file `error` generated by the command `apt-get update 2> error`:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/quantal/Release.gpg  Something wicked happened resolving 'packages.medibuntu.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/quantal/free/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'packages.medibuntu.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/quantal/free/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'packages.medibuntu.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/quantal/non-free/i18n/Translation-en_US  Something wicked happened resolving 'packages.medibuntu.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/quantal/non-free/i18n/Translation-en  Something wicked happened resolving 'packages.medibuntu.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/quantal/free/binary-i386/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'packages.medibuntu.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.medibuntu.org/dists/quantal/non-free/binary-i386/Packages  Something wicked happened resolving 'packages.medibuntu.org:http' (-5 - No address associated with hostname)

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Any idea on how to fix this errors? (bonus - what caused them?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Medibuntu project is not functional anymore, the packages were already merged with the main repositories packages, dropped because too old/buggy or were deemed otherwise unnecessary. There is *no way to fix*. Just remove the repositories from your source.list, so you don't get a warning about "Failed to fetch".

[image]

> The Medibuntu repository has been unmaintained for several months, and has become more and more useless over the years. The project is now considered abandoned, and we recommend to disable the repository if you are using it.
>
> See http://gauvain.pocentek.net/node/61 and http://blogs.kde.org/2013/09/11/medibuntu-disappear-libdvdcss-now-direct-videolan for details.
>
> Thanks to all the Medibuntu users and contributors.

https://launchpad.net/medibuntu/+announcement/11951

Comment: FYI: For me the `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/medibuntu.list` did not work b/c that file did not exist. I had to edit my `/etc/apt/sources.list` and remove the line `deb http://packages.medibuntu.org/ quantal free non-free`

Comment: @stephenmm sorry, I don't catch what you try to say.