# How to install ap-hotspot

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, package-management

I can't seem to install ap-hotspot on ubuntu 12.04.  I read somewhere that I should run the following commands:

```
$ sudo su -
# add-apt-repository ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8
# aptitude update
# aptitude install ap-hotspot
# ap-hotspot configure
# ap-hotspot start
```

But my terminal get stuck on the aptitude update because I get the error `Something wicked happened resolving 'packages.medibuntu.org:http'`.  I was told that's because medibuntu has been shut down.  So I had to go into `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` and delete all things related to medibuntu before I could run aptitude update again.

Then I tried to run `apt-get install ap-hotspot`, but I got the error

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 ap-hotspot : Depends: dnsmasq but it is not going to be installed
```

So then I ran the `apt-get install dnsmasq`, but i got the error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 dnsmasq : Depends: dnsmasq-base (>= 2.59-4) but it is not going to be installed
```

So then I ran the `apt-get install dnsmasq-base` but i got the message:

```
dnsmasq-base is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 260 not upgraded.
```

So how do i get ap-hotspot to work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Failed to fetch medibuntu Something wicked happened resolving (-5 - No address associated with hostname)](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98657/failed-to-fetch-medibuntu-something-wicked-happened-resolving-5-no-address-a)

Comment: Can you provide `dpkg -s dnsmasq-base | grep Version`? The latest version in the precise repo is 2.59-4, but according to the `apt-get install dnsmasq` output, that's not what is installed.

Comment: @Patrick the output of your command is `Version: 2.59-4ubuntu0.1`

Comment: @Braiam I did check that question previously but all it says is how to remove medibuntu, which I've already done as stated in my question.  Removing medibuntu did not help install ap-hotspot.  And also, no one has yet to supply a suggestion on how to provide the dependencies on ap-hotspot.  The question you referenced also does not mention any instructions for installing ap-hotspot, which is my original question. Thanks!

Comment: Edit your question and include the output of `apt-cache policy dnsmasq-base dnsmasq ap-hotspot`

Comment: This solved my problem. Maybe it'll help you as well. See [here][1].


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/470512/ap-hotspot-hangs-at-starting-wireless-hotspot-on-14-04

Answer (score 1):

ap_hotspot is outdated and is not under further development by its dev's.

create_ap is the new hotspot creator for linux distribution available freely.
You make your own by synchronizing with github.

```
git clone https://github.com/oblique/create_ap
cd create ap
make install
```

/* The above method is for debian based distribution */
to initialize create ap :
1) Fire up terminal
2) Type `create_ap` to show up the commands
3) To create internet sharing from same interface network type :

```
create_ap wlan0 wlan0 MyAccessPoint MyPassPhrase
```

source : [Check for extra commands](https://github.com/oblique/create_ap#dependencies)

Answer (score 0):

```
dnsmasq-base:
  Installed: 2.68-1
  Candidate: 2.68-1
  Version table:
 *** 2.68-1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
dnsmasq:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
ap-hotspot:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.3-1~webupd8~4
  Version table:
     0.3-1~webupd8~4 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```